# How to set custom working directory in Xcode for Swift packages?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

So I was trying to set "custom working directory" in Xcode for my Swift package, like this

[image]

You can see I used the good old $(PROJECT_DIR) here.

But when I started to run the project, Xcode prompted me with this

[image]

So how can I make this work?